# Using result of count(*) in oracle in an arithmetic expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

There is a simple issue that I am stuck with and need some help.

I have two different tables, in Oracle 10g, called `BOOK_DETAILS` (primary key- `book_code`) and `BOOK_ISSUE` (foreign and primary key- `book_code`). The `BOOK_ISSUE` table also has a column called `BOOK_ISSUE_STATUS` that holds 'y' or 'n' values depending on if the book is issued or not.

Now I have to do the following simple query - find out the number of books available in the library (i.e. total number of books available - number of books issued).

So I tried doing the following query :-

```
 select count(b.book_code)-count(i.book_code)
 from 
 lms_book_issue i, lms_book_details b
 where
 i.book_issue_status='Y'
 ;
```

But apparently I am not getting the desired result. My logic is to subtract the result of count of number of books issued (which I get from the `BOOK_ISSUE` table) from the result of the count the number of books in the `BOOK_DETAILS` table.

Please let me know where am I going wrong. Moreover the above query simply gives 0 as the result. So an explanation of that as well would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get (total number of books - books with status 'Y'), by :

```
select 
          (select count(book_code) from BOOK_DETAILS) - 
          (select count(book_code) from BOOK_ISSUE where book_issue_status='Y')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic mistake, `count(col)` get you the number of rows in the query with not-null value.

You got 0 simply because the 2 counts gave to the same number.

In this case you even didn't join the 2 tables together with "i.book_code = b.book_code"

But even than it will return you 0,

In your way, the correct select is:

```
select 
    count(b.book_code) - count(i.book_code)
from 
    lms_book_issue i, lms_book_details b
where
    b.book_code = i.book_code(+) AND
    i.book_issue_status = 'Y'
;
```

This way you selected all the books and the books and joined only with issue tab only with rows that have issue=Y, therefor the first count will give you the number of books and the 2nd one will count only the issued books because the rest will be NULL and won't count.